# How to set an empty initial value for Flutter Slider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-slider

Currently the "value" property of [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) is required, however I was wondering if it is possible to create a Slider such that it initially has no value and the thumb is hidden. Then when the user presses along the line, the thumb appears at that point.
[image: Above is what I want the initial state of the slider to look like, below is what it currently looks like as I set value to min as value is required]

I looked at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider but it seems like that package also required values to be set.

Answer (score 0):

I think not, and for good reason.  The function of the `Slider` and the understanding of how it is used is interpreted by the user primarily based on seeing the thumb indicator on a line.  So regardless how you set up the requirements for the slider's usage in your app, the `Slider` control needs to always have a value represented.  You could default the slider value to the min, the max, the middle(-ish), or any valid value.

If you want to ensure the user makes a selection (making it a required field sort of), you could set a `bool` state variable on an ancestor widget (perhaps named `sliderWasTouched`) to `true` when any part of the `Slider` is tapped and whenever the `Slider` changes value (after initialization), and then make that state variable being `true` part of your form field validation.